# NAT Pooling with IPSEC source int on Fortinet 60c

Tags: networking, nat, fortinet

I've been working on this one for a while, and been trying to figgure it out but now I've been banging my head against the wall..

We have the following setup:

Fortinet 60c configured with these interfaces:

- WAN1 - Internet
- WAN2 - Internal (10.0.0.250/24)
- LAN1 - Production (192.168.1.1/24)
- WAN1/IPSEC1 - RemoteSite1 (192.168.40.0/24)

Traffic from RemoteSite1 should be able to reach the whole Production-network, and one server in Internal.

This in it self is not a problem. Routing between remotesite1 and production, and NAT out on Internal.

#### The problem:

The server pleople in RemoteSite1 are using in Internal are used via Telnet, and requires a uniqe IP for each user. When the users are connecting now, they connect to 10.0.0.50, the server recognizes the client as 10.0.0.250 (the IP of the Fortinet on WAN2), fine and dandy, as long as there is only 1 user connected. However, we need 2 clients to be connected at the same time.

Any suggestion on how i can solve this? I can't find any option to acctualy enable NAT Pooling on the device, when using the IPSEC interface as source.

### Questions to further enlighten the case(*)

#### Are you using interface/route based tunnels or policy based?

The tunnels are policy based

#### What does your NAT pool look like?

I've created a VIP-Pool/range: 10.0.0.251-252

#### Where is your NAT pool applied?

It's not applied. When the rule is set with a IPSEC source interface, there's no option to enable NAT-Pooling

- Right now, I'm not able to log on the device, as I'm out of office, so these answers are from the top of my head.

Comment: Append the answers to these questions to your question: Are you using interface/route based tunnels or policy based?  What does your NAT pool look like?  Where is your NAT pool applied?

Comment: Anyone able to help me out here? Still haven't solved this one :-/

Comment: It sounds like you are in inbound NATing on your policy.  Just remove the inbound NATing and you should see client access using their address within `192.168.40.0/24`.  If you want to assign a NAT pool to clients over an single negotiated IPsec tunnel, migrate to interface based VPN and assign a NAT pool in the policies to and from the interface (don't get confused, you are *not* assigning addresses to _VPN clients_ in this instance).  I hate policy based VPN.  Migrating to interface based is very easy.

Comment: I need the inbound NAT, as I don't want the server we are connecting to know any thing else than that there is 1 client connecting from 10.0.0.251 and one from 10.0.0.252.

Comment: OK.  That sounds like a plan.